# Scala - Access Object's field within Class Annotation

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, apache-flink

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```scala
@FunctionHint(
  output = new DataTypeHint(s"is_$role BOOLEAN")
)
class Func(role: String) extends TableFunction[Boolean] {
  ...
}
```

Notice the use of `role` in the Annotation which is a field on the Object being annotated.

Comment: What is the annotation `@FunctionHint` and what does it do? Is it a macro annotation handled by the compiler? Is it an annotation handled at runtime by some framework (like Spring)? I guess what happens with an annotation is the responsibility of an agent handling the annotation. Suspicious is that `@FunctionHint` annotates the **definition** of a class but you want to use `role` that doesn't exist as a String there. `role` exists as a String at a **call** site of the class constructor. So it seems you want to modify your code based on the annotation non-locally.

Comment: It is handled at runtime. This hint describes what the output type of using this function in Flink will be, within the context of Flink's internal type system over tables, which is checked during runtime. In this `Func`'s case, the name of the output column is generically derived from the value of `role`, the Func's impl itself internally operates on `role` as well. Ideally I don't want to make as many implementations of `Func` as there are cases of `role`, if that makes sense.

Comment: Almost certainly not possible. I guess you could do something really weird like e.g. made `@FunctionHint` a macro annotations which would inject code generated from the macro parameter into constructor/companion object (e.g. some `apply` adding logic to constructor) where `role` would be defined. But if you are thinking about runtime reflection, then not, it cannot be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you explained `@FunctionHint` is a Flink annotation, it's Flink responsibility how to handle it at runtime. It seems Flink doesn't support such kind of templating as you want.

You can generate classes with appropriate runtime annotations per each role using a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("Enable macro annotations")
class generateFunc(roles: String*) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro GenerateFuncMacro.impl
}

object GenerateFuncMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val roles = c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new generateFunc(..$rs)" => rs.map {
        case q"${role: String}" => role
      }
    }
    val classes = roles.map(role =>
      q"""
         @_root_.org.apache.flink.table.annotation.FunctionHint(
           output = new _root_.org.apache.flink.table.annotation.DataTypeHint(${s"is_$role BOOLEAN"})
         )
         class ${TypeName(s"Func$role")} extends _root_.org.apache.flink.table.functions.TableFunction[_root_.scala.Boolean] {
         }
      """
    )
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        q"""$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
           ..$body
           ..$classes
        }"""
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@generateFunc("Aa", "Bbb")
object Funcs

//scalac: object Funcs extends scala.AnyRef {
//  def <init>() = {
//    super.<init>();
//    ()
//  };
//  @new FunctionHint(output = new DataTypeHint("is_Aa BOOLEAN")) class FuncAa extends TableFunction[Boolean] {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    <empty>
//  };
//  @new FunctionHint(output = new DataTypeHint("is_Bbb BOOLEAN")) class FuncBbb extends TableFunction[Boolean] {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    <empty>
//  }
//}
```

So you can use `Funcs.FuncAa`, `Funcs.FuncBbb` etc.